# Явное преобразование int к enum и наоборот

Tags: c#

```
 enum Vehicles
{
    car,
    plane,
    ship,
    helicopter,
    truck = plane
}

static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine((Vehicles)1);//truck
    Console.WriteLine((Vehicles)2);//ship
    Console.WriteLine((Vehicles)100);//100
    Console.WriteLine((int)Vehicles.helicopter);// 3
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Я пытаюсь понять, почему, если мы явно приводим интовую переменную(или в нашем случае литерал) выводиться название переменной, которая хранит это значение, а в случае вывода литерала, которого нет в данном перечислении, выводиться сам литерал?  И наоборот - если я привожу поле enum'a(если можно сказать "поле") к int, то выводиться его значение? То есть, при привидении int к Vehicles происходит поиск полей, которые хранят в себе значение этого int'a? Тогда почему в первом выводе truck, а не plane?

Comment: Потому что у `enum` и у `int` по разному определен метод `ToString()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все типы в CLR наследуют от `System.Object` в котором определен виртуальный метод строкового представления текущего объекта – `ToString`. Любой тип может переопределить этот метод, тем самым изменив представление по-умолчанию, которое определено в `System.Object` – вывод полного имени типа.

Например, тип `Int32` (int) переопределяет этот метод для представления хранимого значения в виде форматированного, в зависимости от региональных настроек и формата, числа.

Каждый раз, когда вы определяете перечисление, вы создаете наследника класса `System.Enum` в котором, как вы уже догадались, тоже предопределен метод `ToString` для представления текущего значения перечисления в виде строки. Для вашего перечисления (Vehicles), будет сгенерирован такой IL

```
.class private auto ansi sealed Vehicles
       extends [mscorlib]System.Enum
{
  .field public specialname rtspecialname int32 value__
  .field public static literal valuetype Vehicles car = int32(0x00000000)
  .field public static literal valuetype Vehicles plane = int32(0x00000001)

  ...

  .field public static literal valuetype Vehicles truck = int32(0x00000001)
} // end of class Vehicles
```

Что соответствует примерно вот такому коду (*переводчик из IL я так-себе, поэтому лучше перепроверить* :)

```
sealed class Vehicles : System.Enum
{
    public const Vehicles car   = 0;
    public const Vehicles plane = 1;

    ...

    public const Vehicles truck = 1;
}
```

Теперь о том, как метод `ToString` который используется методом `Console.WriteLine` находит имя поля. В .NET есть специальный механизм, называемый рефлексия, при помощи которого можно получать информацию о произвольных типах (например, имена полей и их значений) при помощи этого механизма Enum просматривает список полей, и если есть совпадения по значению – то возвращает это имя. На практике за это отвечает этот код, который вызывается из метода `Enum.ToString`

```
private static String InternalFormat(RuntimeType eT, Object value)
{
    if (!eT.IsDefined(typeof(System.FlagsAttribute), false))
    {
        String retval = GetName(eT, value);
        if (retval == null)
            return value.ToString();
        else
            return retval;

        ...
    }
```

Из него хорошо видно, что если у перечисление нет атрибута `Flags` то метод должен просто вернуть имя поля или, в случае несовпадения, вернуть значение.

> Тогда почему в первом выводе truck, а не plane

Как я говорил выше, что имена всех полей и значений выбираются при помощи рефлексии. Затем код сортирует *значения* полей и при помощи [двоичного поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) ищет совпадение. Таким образом, поиск просто вернет первое совпадение. За это отвечает этот код из `System.Enum`

```
Array values = GetEnumRawConstantValues();
int index = BinarySearch(values, value);

if (index >= 0)
{
    string[] names = GetEnumNames();
    return names[index];
}
```

Можно попробовать манипулировать этим поиском, поместив одинаковые значения на границу отрезков:

```
enum Vehicles
{
    car         = 0,
    plane       = 1,
    cat         = 2,
    ship        = 2,
    helicopter  = 3,
    truck       = 4
}

...

string name = ((Vehicles) 2).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(name); // cat
```

Но всё таки лучше присваивать разные значения полям перечисления :)